# How to plot Energy line diagram

Tags: plotting, chemistry

how to plot like this picture，In chemistry the ''Energy line diagram'' is important.
I can use "chemdraw",but I have to manually adjust the data and everything, which is a hassle, right.
[image]

Comment: Edit the question to include sample data in the form that it will be received or input. Also explain the horizontal spacing and labels.

Comment: Start small first, just plot a single line with the grid work and axes.  Horizontal axis can be {0,1,2...10} for example.  Then first black line would be line1=Graphics@ Line[{2,0},{3,3}}].  Then Show[line1,Axes->True].  Then just add the other constructs to this manually at first then if you wish construct a general function which takes a table of species and energies and generates the plot.  This way I think you'll get much more out of this than just a plot. :)

Comment: Take a look at [`SciDraw`](https://scidraw.nd.edu/). It was born out of a need to draw energy level schemes and it extends the scientific diagram drawing ability of Mathematica considerably. Otherwise, @josh makes some every good points! :-)